# Why is there an extra prototype in this object's prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function called `protoDepth` that calculates the depth of an object's prototype chain:

```
function protoDepth(obj) {                                                                                                                                                                   
  var depth = 0                                                                                                                                                                              
    , proto                                                                                                                                                                                  
  while (proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {                                                                                                                                               
    obj = proto                                                                                                                                                                              
    depth++                                                                                                                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                                                                                          
  return depth                                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

Then I wrote a test for this function, which unexpectedly failed:

```
describe('`protoDepth`:', function() {                                                                                                                                                
  function A() {}                                                                                                                                                    
  function B() {}                                                                                                                                                    
  var a, b                                                                                                                                                                                 

  beforeEach(function() {                                                                                                                                                                  
    a = new A                                                                                                                                                                              
    B.prototype = a                                                                                                                                                                        
    b = new B                                                                                                                                                                              
  })                                                                                                                                                                                       

  it('provides the correct prototype depth.', function() {                                                                                                                                 
    expect(protoDepth(b)).toBe(2)                                                                                                                                                     
  })                                                                                                                                                                                       
})
```

I expected the depth to be `2`; that is, `depth++`, I thought, would only be executed twice:

- `depth` is `0`
- The prototype of `b` is `a`; depth is `1`
- The prototype of `a` is `Object`; depth is `2`
- The prototype of `Object` is `null`; end of story.

But this is wrong. It appears that the prototype of `a` is `a`. Here's the local scope at the first line of execution:

[image]

[image]

What's going on here? Why is A the `__proto__` of a? Since I didn't set `A.prototype`, isn't it `Object` by default?

Comment: Every constructor function has its own distinct prototype object by default. *That* object is a plain object, so it has the Object prototype as its prototype.

Comment: "Every constructor function has its own distinct prototype object by default" <- meaning, if you don't set `Function.prototype`, `Function.prototype` will be `Function`?

Comment: No, not `Function.prototype`. Every function *instance* has a "prototype" property that's initialized to a new, unique object.  If you create two separate functions (like your "A" and "B"), each will have a distinct prototype object.

Comment: A much simpler way to perform this test is: setup: `var a = Object.create(Object.create(Object.create({})))`, test: `expect(protoDepth(a)).toBe(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I didn't set `A.prototype`, isn't it Object by default?

No, it's an empty Object by default (that is created together with the `function A`). So your prototype chain of `b` is `a` (`== B.prototype`), then `A.prototype`, then `Object.prototype`, then `null`.

Comment: Got it—many thanks. The key misunderstanding I had here was that `Object` is—of course, duh, obviously—a __function__.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the prototype of `B` should be set:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Now, the result is 3 because the prototype chain contains: `B.prototype`, `A.prototype` and `Object.prototype`.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p3KTZ/2/) (I added some `console.log` calls to show the results), the debugger now shows this:

```
B {constructor: function}
  __proto__: B
    constructor: function B() { }
    __proto__: A
      constructor: function A() { }
      __proto__: Object
```